# Backtracking function inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am **backtracking** a code to find out what it actually does. I got into the function `getResults()` but I am unable to understand how would the function `success()` get triggered here. Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

```
function getResults(u) {
//alert("Inside get results");
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp", 
        url: u,
        success: function(res) {                                                    
        alert("Inside success");                                                        
              $("#status").hide();                                                      
              if (res.data.length) {
                  // do something                                                       
            } else {
              // do something else
            }; 
        } 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's an asynchronous function. If you're new to that concept I suggest you read up on it first.

Answer (score 0):

`success` is simply what happens when the data at the other end of the URL comes back.

FYI, you might want to look into the shorthand `getJSON`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/